# How to get btc address balance via electrum json rpc

Tags: php, blockchain, bitcoin

I have installed electrum and run it as a daemon in my ubuntu server.

I'm trying to pull BTC address balance, my curl code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:7777");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD , 'user:RZrelBOuhdFsD2BDhDKPOg==');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"id\":\"curltext\",\"method\":\"getaddressbalance\",\"params\":[1CxEFYV4jfKH4WYPc3tNdxUEUQqBNG7veg]}");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }
//curl_close ($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result,1));

?>
```

I'm getting: NULL when I execute it.

my question is: how can I use php+curl with electrum daemon to get btc address balance into an array?

Comment: `dd()` is a function that exist in the Laravel framework. It's basically the same as: `var_dump($someVariable); die;`. If you're not using Laravel or have a custom function called `dd()`, don't use it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I've just changed that to var_dump however I'm getting NULL. Please check my code

Comment: We can't possibly know how that API should be used. We didn't develop it. If it's some application you installed, then refer to it's manual. If it's still unclear, you should contact the developers. Check if they have some support or forum. Also, the answer you got this from was over three years old. Are you sure it's the same version or that works the same way as it did then?